# WordPress add a class for newest posts

Tags: php, wordpress, class, post

Does sombody know how i can add a class to the newest posts in WordPress. And what i mean with the newest is the lasts posts that are added in the last minut?

My code now:

```
<?php 
    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'category_name'     => 'profiel',
        'posts_per_page'    => 48,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'meta_key'          => 'online',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    ));
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="profiel">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="404 not-found">
        <h3>Not Found</h3>
        <div class="post-excerpt">
            <p>Sorry, but there are no more posts here... Please try going back to the <a href="<?php echo remove_query_arg( 'pg' ); ?>">main page</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif;

    wp_reset_query();

    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'mid_size' => 10
    ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current time, remove 60 seconds compare that to the timestamp of your post. If your post timestamp is greater than the timestamp from a minute ago then it's new.

```
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="profiel <?= (get_the_time('U') > (time()-60)) ? 'new' : '' ?>">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</div>
```